# JavaScript date convertor

Tags: javascript, datetime-format

I am using Yahoo YQL API to fetch the upcoming cricket match list, now the issue is - the date format is something very different. I am unable to convert the date format using JavaScript.

**Date format received from Yahoo:** 2016-04-03T19:00:00+05:30 
**Date format I need:** Mon, 03 April 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var d = new Date('2016-04-03T19:00:00+05:30');
document.write(d.toUTCString().slice(0,16));
```

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_toutcstring

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot @Leo

Comment: Thanks @SanjayAchar , please mark the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to parse the date.

```
var date = Date.parse("2016-04-03T19:00:00+05:30");
```

You can format the date manually by calling the members of [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
var days= ["Mon", "Thu", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
var months = [ ... ];

var result = [];

// Day of week:
result.push(days[date.getDay()]); 

result.push(", ");

// Day of month:
result.push(date.getDate());

result.push(" ");

// Month:
result.push(months[date.getMonth()]); // Note that getMonth() is zero-based.

result.push(" ");

// Year:
result.push(date.getYear());

console.log(result.join(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date('2016-04-03T19:00:00+05:30');
```

returns d as

```
Sun Apr 03 2016 19:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

now use functions to get elements like

```
d.getDate() returns 3
```

[Date functions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)